# RegEx match expression or nothing

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression for IP address with optional portnumber.
I now need to change it so that it will match if nothing or if something then it must be a valid IP with optional portnumber.

My regex is...

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b[.: ]?[0-9]?[0=9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0=9]?
```

Note: My check for optional port number is not ideal, I know, as it is possible to enter 99999 whereas the max port number is 65535, but I can live with that at the moment.

Comment: This problem is more easily solvable with other methods than regexes since it involves numeric ranges.

Comment: A regular expression always matches something or nothing. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: By "nothing" I think he means the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(?:[.:]\b([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]))?$
```

**Explanation**

```
# ^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(?:[.:]\b([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]))?$
# 
# Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
# Match the regular expression below «(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}»
#    Exactly 3 times «{3}»
#    Match the regular expression below «(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])»
#       Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «25[0-5]»
#          Match the characters “25” literally «25»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” «[0-5]»
#       Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «2[0-4][0-9]»
#          Match the character “2” literally «2»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” «[0-4]»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#       Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «1[0-9][0-9]»
#          Match the character “1” literally «1»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#       Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[1-9]?[0-9]»
#          Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]?»
#             Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#    Match the character “.” literally «\.»
# Match the regular expression below «(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])»
#    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «25[0-5]»
#       Match the characters “25” literally «25»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” «[0-5]»
#    Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «2[0-4][0-9]»
#       Match the character “2” literally «2»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” «[0-4]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#    Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «1[0-9][0-9]»
#       Match the character “1” literally «1»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#    Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[1-9]?[0-9]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]?»
#          Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
# Match the regular expression below «(?:[.:]\b([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]))?»
#    Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
#    Match a single character present in the list “.:” «[.:]»
#    Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
#    Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])»
#       Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[1-9][0-9]{0,3}»
#          Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{0,3}»
#             Between zero and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{0,3}»
#       Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[1-5][0-9]{4}»
#          Match a single character in the range between “1” and “5” «[1-5]»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{4}»
#             Exactly 4 times «{4}»
#       Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «6[0-4][0-9]{3}»
#          Match the character “6” literally «6»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” «[0-4]»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{3}»
#             Exactly 3 times «{3}»
#       Or match regular expression number 4 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «65[0-4][0-9]{2}»
#          Match the characters “65” literally «65»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” «[0-4]»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
#             Exactly 2 times «{2}»
#       Or match regular expression number 5 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «655[0-2][0-9]»
#          Match the characters “655” literally «655»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “2” «[0-2]»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#       Or match regular expression number 6 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «6553[0-5]»
#          Match the characters “6553” literally «6553»
#          Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” «[0-5]»
# Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: All, Thanks so much for your input. @Cylian your answer worked best for me although looking at Tomalak's version below I was wondering why you only match the 0-255 exactly 3 and not 4 times. I am using the regex in a aspnet regex validation control. It was failing validation if the textbox was empty. I then realised that there is a parameter of ValidationIsRequired. I set this to false and now the textbox can be empty or if it does contain something it must pass the IP and optional portnumber validation. Thanks for all your inputs.

Comment: I now understand... Match 3 times exactly first with period and the once again as the last quad will not have a period on the end...

Answer (score 1):

The [regex number range generator](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) I found creates for `0 .. 255`

```
0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
```

and for `1 .. 65535`:

```
0*([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])
```

Taking the first bit, your IP address regex can be shortened to

```
(?:0*(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.|\b)){4}
```

So the general structure of the expression would be

```
OCTET_EXPRESSION ::= 0*(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
PORT_EXPRESSION  ::= 0*(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])

(
  (?:
    OCTET_EXPRESSION
    (?:\.|\b)
  ){4}
)
(
  (?:
    :
    PORT_EXPRESSION
  )?
)
```

giving two groups (IP and port, if applicable).

```
^((?:0*(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.|\b)){4})(?::(0*(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])))?$
```

http://rubular.com/r/IPNJrTp06y

If you can, use a small parser. Splitting on `.` and `:` and checking the validity of the resulting numeric ranges is tivial in any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `|` at the end:

```
current_regex|
```

This matches *`current_regex`* or the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Since each octet or whatever you call it maxes out at 255, and an IP address is either 4 [or 6] sets, why not parse the string into an array and just check that way?

For example:

```
var ipAddress = "111.11.0.255:1234";
var ipAndPort = ipAddress.Split(':');

var ipArray = ipAndPort[0].Split('.');
var port = ipAndPort.Length == 2 ? ipAndPort[1] : 80;

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   switch (i)
   {
      case 0:
         if (ipArray[i] <= 0 || ipArray[i] > 255)
            return false;
         break;
      default:
         if (ipArray[i] < 0 || ipArray[i] > 255)
            return false;
         break;
   }

   if (port > 65535 || port < 1)
      return false;

   return true;
}
```

Comment: The OP did not indicate JavaScript, though.

Comment: @Tomalak the same idea works in any language, even if it's represented in one language here.